# send all routes through a final method

Tags: node.js, express

I am using NodeJS and express. Express supports middleware which is real handy for sending all routes through a "pre-processor" for authentication and such.

Is there an equivalent for a post-processor?

I want to update the token on all the responses. This is so as the user "works" their authentication wont expire because I always refresh it.

There may be some confusion so I am going to add a sample piece of code:

```
router.get('/auth', [auth], async function({ user }, res) {

  …
  <<code to generate new token>>
  return res.header('Authentication', 'Basic ' + token).send(200);
});
```

So at the end of every route I want to call the following code to update the header:

```
  <<code to generate new token>>
  return res.header('Authentication', 'Basic ' + token).send(200);
```

[auth] is the middleware. I was wondering if there is a "endware" that is as easy as the middleware to send all reponses through before going out to the user so I don't manually have to copy the token generation and header code in each and every route.

Thx

Gina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `next` callback from your route handler to call the next middleware like this

```
router.get('/auth', [auth], async function({ user }, res, next) {
    ...
    next()
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    <<code to generate new token>>
    res.header('Authentication', 'Basic ' + token).send(200);
})
```

Or this way

```
const addAuth = (req, res) => {
    <<code to generate new token>>
    res.header('Authentication', 'Basic ' + token).send(200);
}

router.get('/auth', [auth], async function({ user }, res, next) {
    ...
    next()
}, addAuth);
```

But you must be careful to only use `res.send` function once because it will close the response stream, but you can use `res.write`/`res.end`.

Comment: @Rami_Jarrar  ohhh, so I can start writing the header in the resp, say after auth but before the actual method code?

Comment: I'm not sure I get it! but anyway I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in post processor for Express responses, unfortunately. One solution to this problem we have implemented at my company is to group up all pending properties of the response into a `res.pending` object, and then have a final middleware that actually completes the HTTP response through `res.send()`. This utilizes the fact that [Express middleware order matters](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) and can be used to strategically delay the post-processing step until all middleware has finished.

One of the nice benefits from this solution, in addition to the perk you called out of a singular point in code for auth / metrics / response handling, is that you can make later middleware portions know the response body before it is sent. Otherwise, if a non-terminal middleware calls `res.send()`, no following middleware has access to the res data.

Comment: I like that idea. I am trying to put it together with Rami's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am combining Rami's answer and jakemingolla.

I added a middleware handler "refreshToken". This generates a new token and adds it to the res.pendingToken.

```
router.get('/auth', [auth, refreshToken], async function(req, res) {

  …

  if (res.pendingToken) {
    return res.header('Authentication', 'Basic ' + res.pendingToken).sendStatus(200);
  }

  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

-Gina